# Git synchronization issue in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github, repository

I synchronize my Eclipse projects with my work machine and my home machine using Git. Recently  I have a problem with synchronizing in one machine.

The structure of the code in one machine and Git hub is given below

```
Project/
    -bin
    -src
    -doc
    -.settings
    -.classpath
    -.project
```

The structure I get when I synchronize with the machine I have a problem is

```
Project/
    -bin/
        -src
    -src
    -doc
    -.setting
    -.classpath
    -.project
```

There are two copies of src with the relevant source files inside which invalidated the package and project references. I tried many times including deleting the project from the hard disk and then re-fetching it but it does not solve the problem. This pattern of problem is persistent with my other new projects as well and I run into same type of issue which I simply cannot solve.

**Additional Observations**

After trying it in different approaches after my initial post it was observed that it was not the Git-hub or the Git synchronization that creates trouble. It is rather to do with eclipse loading the project.

So as a remedy I now loaded the project in question in my local repo as a file system and the problem was solved. If it was imported as an existing project then the problem will crop up again.

So, according to the above observation it is something to do with eclipse loading the project and I looked at the .project file and .settings folder to identify possible causes but could not.

As of now I know how to solve this problem but I do not know why this happens. Would appreciate if somebody could explain me why this happens.

Comment: What `git status` does return? Is there any symlink?

Comment: @VonC what you mean by git status? It does not give any error messages and I don't know how to look up for statuses. I don't think there are any symlinks.